# Combine row of jsons into one single jsons in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a JSON Column in each row like below

`"{"car":12}"`

`"{"bike":9}"`

How to make it into one row like this

`{"car":12, "bike":9}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want an array as the result, you will need to create your own aggregate function:

```sql
create aggregate jsonb_merge_agg(jsonb) 
(
  sfunc = jsonb_concat(jsonb, jsonb),
  stype = jsonb
);
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
select jsonb_merge_agg(the_column)
from the_table;
```

If you have multiple values with the same key, the "last one" will overwrite all previous ones.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=36e97f068cb7f08dbc43dc2b064980de)

Comment: any options without using functions?

Comment: What's the problem with the function?

Comment: in our project we are not using functions. thats the reason asking in sql query itself

Comment: Then it's time to use them. I doubt there is any alternative that would be more efficient or readable without using a custom aggregate. Besides it's impossible to do it completely without a "function" - you always need some kind of aggregation function.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name .. Using the same function which you wrote above and I got the output which I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about my earlier mistake.

You can do this like so:

```
with data (jcol) as (
  values ('{"car": 12}'::jsonb), ('{"bike":9}')
)
select jsonb_object_agg(k, v) 
  from data 
 cross join lateral jsonb_each(jcol) as j(k,v);

    jsonb_object_agg    
------------------------
 {"car": 12, "bike": 9}
(1 row)
```

Comment: I know it already. and i dont want to get it as Array of JSONs. . I want to use as json object values only

Comment: @JohnsonAnthony  Sorry I missed your requirements in my earlier answer.  I have updated my answer to use `jsonb_each()` and `jsonb_object_agg()`.